# Who cares about metadata?

Tags: metadata, accessibility, pdf-a, hyperxmp

I do add metadata to my LaTeX documents since more than a decade. `hyperref` and `hyperxmp` provide an interface to do so. Recently the possibilities have expanded with hyperxmp. You can add more and more stuff. In theory, this looks great.

I started asking myself who actually uses this metadata. Tags like `pdfcontactphone` are hidden well behind nested windows in Acrobat. I did a quick test in Acrobat DC by specifying `pdflang` and reading the document loud. To my surprise Acrobat does not care. Even when the text-to-speech packages are installed in Windows and the language is correctly specified in the PDFs the reader does not switch the voice.

So, can you give examples where (XMP) metadata make a difference today in real life?

Where is the advantage of having the authors in a list instead of a single string?

Who cares about multilingual document titles?

Realized use cases of author contact fields?

Who benefits from [Jabref XMP bibliography](https://docs.jabref.org/advanced/xmp), [Journal Article Version](https://www.niso.org/sites/default/files/2017-08/RP-8-2008.pdf) or XMP stored [ORCID](https://orcid.org/)?

Comment: Future generations of historians will thank you

Answer (score 3):

I make physics quiz, where I need to include pictures, so I put the filename of the pictures in meta data. Always I can find the pictures if I need to reuse any question. Maybe no a fair use of metadata, but works fir me

Comment: Which tool do you use to search?